# read from XML source with custom schema errors

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

Seems like a very simple issue, but very annoying..

I have an XML file with the following structure:

```
<A attr1="Str1" attr2="Long1">
    <B attr3="Str1" attr4="Str2" attr5="Long1"/>
    <B attr3="Str1" attr4="Str2" attr5="Long1"/>
    ....
    <B attr3="Str1" attr4="Str1" attr5="Integer1"/>
```

My goal is to read it into a Spark (Pyspark) DataFrame to process it later.

I am using the Databricks package. When I run the following code:

```
df = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.xml') \

                    .option('rowTag','A') \
                    .option('attributePrefix','att_') \
                    .load('s3a://path.to.my.xml')
```

The resulting df's schema (auto infered) is the following:

```
root
 |-- A: array (nullable=true)
     |-- element: struct (containsNull=true)
           |-- _VALUE: string(nullable=true)
           |-- att_attr3: string(nullable=true)
           |-- att_attr4: long(nullable=true)
           |-- att_attr5: long(nullable=true)
 |-- att_attr1: string(nullable=true)
 |-- att_attr2: long(nullable=true)
```

The problem is the ***attr4*** in this case, which I expect to be of the type **string**, but is treated as **long**.

Every *custom schema* which I tried to set, was resulting in some internal error, or 0 records in the dataframe.

Please help :)

(Spark v. 2.0.0)

Answer (score -1):

OK... found the appropriate way to set the schema so the XML will be parsed proparely. Some minor syntax issues. If you are interested or have similar problem, please comment and I will wirte it here.

Comment: can u please upload the fix ?